# Novel about near-future AI-controlled Air Force fighting human-controlled Navy

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence, mind-control

I've been looking to track down a book about an AI controlling people's minds.

By wearing a piece of technology, the AI could take over your body and make you do things. It takes place in the near future and doesn't include robots.

The significant detail that I remember was that later in the novel the protagonist was told that the Air Force was mostly under the control of the AI, but the Navy was not. This was after society had discovered the AI and the protagonist was trying to flee to safety to a human controlled settlement.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any character or place names, or what the cover art looked like?